# For loop going crazy! Nested for loop GOTO

Tags: windows, for-loop, batch-file, cmd, goto

EDIT: I think the for loop is running into the subdirectories of the subdirectories, returning 'Icon' folder from each subdirectory and passing that on as the first argument. I need to make the first loop only run through the first set of subdirectories

Example directory structure:

Files\01\Icon
Files\02\Icon
Files\03\Icon

So it runs through 01, then 02, then 03, then 01\Icon, 02\Icon, 03\Icon. It needs to stop at the first level.

The for loop is going wrong! Can you help me fix it, please?

It seems that the nested for loop runs faaar too many times, it is just needed to run once to find the file name of the *.ico. Not sure if there would be a quicker way to find the *.ico. I don't know of any way to return the icons filename without a for loop though.

```
@ECHO OFF

set ICOINI=Desktop.ini

for /D /R "%cd%" %%d IN (*) do call :Write_File %%~nd

goto :End_File

:Write_File

attrib +s "%CD%\%1"
echo Set Attributes for: %cd%\%1

for %%F in ("%CD%\%1\Icon\*.ico") do set ICO=%%~nxF

IF EXIST "%CD%\%1\%ICOINI%" attrib -a -s -h "%1\%ICOINI%"

echo [.ShellClassInfo]>"%CD%\%1\%ICOINI%"
echo IconResource="%CD:~2%\%1\%ICO%">>"%CD%\%1\%ICOINI%"
echo InfoTip="%ICO:~0,-4%">>"%CD%\%1\%ICOINI%"

attrib -a +s +h "%CD%\%1\%ICOINI%"

goto :EOF

:End_File

Pause
```

Comment: why dont u try a `for-loop` nested in a `for-loop`, which I think would work better then a `for-loop`, nested in a `goto-loop` nested into a `for-loop`. Do this by using `( )` after the `do` in both loops.

Comment: The /D /R loop is recursive with the /R so it is running through the tree.  The other for loop is running to pick a file name - it's not doing anything else.  What issue do you see?

Comment: The result is it works for all the directories, once it has done that it loops trying to find %CD%\Icon which doesn't exist. It runs through around ten times trying to find something which isn't there!

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
set "ICO="
for %%F in ("%CD%\%~1\Icon\*.ico") do if not defined ICO set "ICO=%%~nxF"
```